# Javascript Bitwise Operators

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out some differences between C# and Javascript. Ok, take this code in Javascript:

```
var j = 0x783a9b23;
var bt = ((16843134 ^ (16843134 - 1)) * j);
```

After executing this, "bt" will be 6051320169.

Now after doing this in C#:

```
int j = 0x783a9b23;
int bt = ((16843134 ^ (16843134 - 1)) * j);
```

"bt" will be 1756352873. Certainly not the same. Any ideas why Javascript is not seeing how C# sees it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this to make it work like in C#

```
var j = 0x783a9b23;
var bt = ((16843134 ^ (16843134 - 1)) * j);
bt = bt % 2147483647
```

This is because in c# your integer overflows the limit of 2,147,483,647.

Comment: +1 or `int bt = checked((16843134 ^ (16843134 - 1)) * j);` to reveal the overflow

Comment: Woah, this is sweet. Always took this type of stuff for granit for so long until now when I really need to understand lower level things as Im converting some chess code to Javascript just as an exercise to learn more. Thanks a million.